# Can we configure Azure application Insights to only sample the request telemetry and not the rest

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am using azure AI for telemetry in my project. But AI is pretty costly and it seems to keep using AI we need enable sampling.

I wanted to know how the sampling is done, can we configure it on the level of telemetry type. Would it be possible to only sample request telemetry and not the trace or exception telemetry.Also is it possible to only sample the success case and not the failure cases

Answer (score 1):

Yes to all. [Here is a lengthy article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling) about all sampling  types and available configuration in Application Insights.

Shortly:

- Sampling can be set at a certain percent or sampling can be adaptive
  and set to a certain "items per second" level (and it will adjust
  percentage dynamically);
- Sampling can include/exclude certain types with `<ExcludedTypes>`
  added to the sampling node in ApplicationInsights.config file or via
  code;
- Sampling is enabled by default if you install
  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web or
  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore Nuget packages
- You can set your own filters with [Telemetry Processors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor) to sample
  out unwanted telemetry such as successful of fast requests and
  similar..